# Grouping/Aggregating by 2 Columns in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to use the aggregate function in R and I'd appreciate some guidance.  About the only way I could get aggregate to work was by following the syntax given [here](https://statisticsglobe.com/aggregate-function-in-r/).

Given the data

```
data <- data.frame(alpha = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
               beta = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4),
               gamma = c(.1,.2,.3,.2,.4,.1,.3,.5))
```

I would like to aggregate by the columns `'alpha'` and `'beta'`.  If I was just aggregating by `'alpha'`, for example, I could just do:

```
aggregate(x = data[ , colnames(data) != "alpha"], 
          by = list(data$alpha), 
          FUN = sum)
```

Trying

```
aggregate(x = data[ , colnames(data) != "alpha" | colnames(data) != "beta"], 
          by = list(data$alpha, data$beta), 
          FUN = sum)
```

didn't work.  Could someone help me find the correct syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected result? I.e. do you want to get the sum of gamma by all possible combinations of alpha and beta pr do you want to get the sum of gamma by aggregating alpha and then also get the sum of gamma when aggregating beta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the formula interface might be easier here:

```
aggregate(gamma ~ alpha + beta, data = data, FUN = sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(alpha = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
           beta = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4),
           gamma = c(.1,.2,.3,.2,.4,.1,.3,.5)) %>% 
  group_by(alpha) %>% 
  summarise(across(.fns = sum))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  alpha  beta gamma
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     6   0.8
2     2    14   1.3
```

?